# menue bar and launcher

Tags: unity, compiz, xorg, unity-dash, fglrx

I recently installed Xorg 1.11 and fglrx 12.6 on my machine and after restarting system that worked as well .
that was good also at the game time .
the unity menuebar/launcher and panel left after i switched back from win7 .(ubuntu 2d havent this issue)
what is the problem ? Any idea ?

I tried to reset unuity

```
hamed@linu-pc:/usr/bin$ sudo unity --reset
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1400004

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x320078b

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:4728): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:44 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:139 Unable to load GDesktopAppInfo for 'ubiquity-gtkui.desktop'
ERROR 2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity.launcher.trashlaunchericon TrashLauncherIcon.cpp:62 Could not create file monitor for trash uri: Operation not supported
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch paths: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
Initializing unityshell options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00090!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a1!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc000a1!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Initializing annotate options...done
Initializing blur options...done
Initializing clone options...done
Initializing commands options...done
Initializing cube options...done
Initializing obs options...done
Initializing rotate options...done
Initializing screenshot options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing switcher options...done
Initializing water options...done
Initializing wobbly options...done
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-impress.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/activity-log-manager-ccpanel.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Unable to find group 'X-Activity-Log-Manager Shortcut Group'
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:45 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch paths: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:46 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:182 Unable to connect to proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:11:46 unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:182 Unable to connect to proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Nautilus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/bin/nautilus exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:21:15 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:21:30 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:21:38 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:23:06 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:24:47 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
WARN  2013-07-20 19:29:36 unity <unknown>:0 Failed to fetch path: Process /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon exited with status 1
```

Data about kernel fglrx and Xorg :

```
root@linu-pc:~# uname -a
Linux linu-pc 3.2.0-49-generic-pae #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 18 18:00:21 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
root@linu-pc:~# X -version

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic i686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux linu-pc 3.2.0-49-generic-pae #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 18 18:00:21 UTC 2013 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic-pae root=UUID=9e5ae4eb-3013-43c9-a790-a9cdd85f786d ro recovery nomodeset
Build Date: 11 April 2013  01:04:30PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.13 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
root@linu-pc:~# fglrxinfo 
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11627 Compatibility Profile Context
```

root@linu-pc:/usr/bin# sudo lspci -v

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV730XT [Radeon HD 4670] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 0276
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fdfe0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    I/O ports at ee00 [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fdf00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
    Kernel modules: fglrx, radeon
```

root@linu-pc:/usr/bin# sudo lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
pppoe                  17513  2 
pppox                  13158  1 pppoe
pci_stub               12550  1 
vboxpci                22911  0 
vboxnetadp             13328  0 
vboxnetflt             27240  0 
vboxdrv               252228  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
rfcomm                 38139  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
bluetooth             158479  10 rfcomm,bnep
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
lp                     17455  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1 
snd_hda_intel          32719  5 
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
rndis_wlan             28472  0 
snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
cfg80211              178877  1 rndis_wlan
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
rndis_host             13560  1 rndis_wlan
cdc_ether              13312  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 25214  3 rndis_wlan,rndis_host,cdc_ether
joydev                 17393  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
snd                    62218  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse                86520  0 
sp5100_tco             13495  0 
parport_pc             32114  1 
parport                40930  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
mac_hid                13077  0 
i2c_piix4              13093  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
k10temp                12990  0 
ati_agp                13242  0 
soundcore              14635  1 snd
wmi                    18744  0 
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
fglrx                2909978  166 
usbhid                 41937  0 
hid                    77428  1 usbhid
firewire_ohci          40172  0 
firewire_core          56940  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12627  1 firewire_core
pata_atiixp            12999  0 
floppy                 60184  0 
r8169                  56368  0
```

update :

```
root@linu-pc:/# /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series
OpenGL version string:  3.3.11627 Compatibility Profile Context

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
root@linu-pc:/# sudo -- lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV730XT [Radeon HD 4670]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fdfe0000-fdfeffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fdf00000-fdf1ffff
```